# How to add class window resize method vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

I want to add a class to a div when the user resizes the window and reach a specific width.

Here's my code

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize);
},

methods: {
  handleWindowResize() {
   this.windowWidth = event.currentTarget.innerWidth;
  },
}
```

I'm not sure after this. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

see example:

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize () {
      let el = document.querySelector('.class-anchor')
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        el.classList.add('you-class')
      } else {
        el.classList.remove('you-class')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```